# Why is printf producing strange output in my simple script?

Tags: c

I am an intermediate Python programmer, but I am trying to learn C. It is an extremely frustrating experience so far.

Why does this simple code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char name[15] = "George Lopez"; /* string representing your name */
char birthday[6] = "01-30-92"; /* string representing your bday */
int phone_number; /* declair int representing phone number */

int main() {
  phone_number = 2222223333; /* int representing your phone number */
  printf("You said your name was: %s\n", name);
  printf("And your birthday is %s?\n", birthday);
  printf("And, so I can call you, your number is %d\n", phone_number); 
  return(0); /* exit program normally */
}
```

produce this output when the phone number is 2222223333:

```
You said your name was: George Lopez
And your birthday is 01-30-92?
And, so I can call you, your number is -2072743963
```

This output when the phone number is 9992223333:

```
error: 4_1_myinfo.c:16:3: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
   phonenumber = 9992223333;
```

And this output when the phone number is 1112223333:

```
You said your name was: George Lopez
And your birthday is 01-30-92?
And, so I can call you, your number is 1112223333
```

I suspect this has to do with how C deals with integers. Perhaps, ints in C have a smaller maximum length than ints in python and this is resulting in wanky output?

Comment: Beyond the bounds of the array: `char birthday[6] = "01-30-92";`, causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: `birthday` should cause a mandatory diagnostic on compilation. If you (can and do) ignore that, it is not a valid string, so passing it to `printf` as a string is UB.

Comment: Despite its representation as a string of digits, a phone number isn't *really* a number. Use a string as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of major issues here.

First, when using C-strings, avoid defining the size of the buffer if you can, like so:

```
char name[] = "George Lopez"; /* string representing your name */
char birthday[] = "01-30-92"; /* string representing your bday */
```

If you MUST pre-defined the maximum string length, use a common limit, like so:

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN 256
char name[MAX_STR_LEN] = "George Lopez"; /* string representing your name */
char birthday[MAX_STR_LEN] = "01-30-92"; /* string representing your bday */
```

If you don't plan on modifying them in the future, make them `const` like so:

```
const char* name = "George Lopez"; /* string representing your name */
const char* birthday = "01-30-92"; /* string representing your bday */
```

In your case, you defined a character array that could only hold 6 characters, but tried to stuff 9 characters in it "01-30-92", plus the trailing `\0` character included automatically. Big mistake.

The second major issue is that you are attempting to fit an integer literal into a data type which can not hold it. In C, the maximum signed 32-bit value, `2,147,483,647`, is defined as `INT_MAX` in `<limits.h>`. You should make your code like so:

long long int phone_number = 2222222222L;

Notice the trailing numeric literal suffix, `L`? That's to allow your code to compile, and using a `long long int` is necessary to create a variable that can actually store the value itself.

Finally, you should consider using strings to hold the phone number. You aren't doing any algebraic/mathematical manipulations on it, so there's no need to use an integral data type to represent it.

**Code Listing (Modified)**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char name[] = "George Lopez"; /* string representing your name */
char birthday[] = "01-30-92"; /* string representing your bday */
long long int phone_number; /* declair int representing phone number */

int main() {
  phone_number = 2222223333L; /* int representing your phone number */
  printf("You said your name was: %s\n", name);
  printf("And your birthday is %s?\n", birthday);
  printf("And, so I can call you, your number is %lld\n", phone_number); 
  return(0); /* exit program normally */
}
```

**Sample Output**

---

```
You said your name was: George Lopez
And your birthday is 01-30-92?
And, so I can call you, your number is 2222223333
```

Comment: Bad idea to move from array to pointer. BTW, why didn't you make the pointer constant as well?

Comment: @Deduplicator If the data is intended to be read only, a pointer approach is perfectly fine. No need to make the pointer `const` necessarily either. It's just the data being preserved, not the pointer itself.

Comment: What does that needless indirection (and extra variable) buy you? (There might have been some use for it if it was `static const`, though that'S debatable) Also, I'm sure you wanted suffix `LL` for a `long long`, not `L`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Could you provide an example of what you're getting at? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say. In both case, addressing the array and addressing the `const char*`, the notation is the same. There is also no use of the unary indirection operator in my code. That's just declaring a pointer variable. Also, which "extra variable" are you referring to? If you're referring to `MAX_STR_LEN`, it's not a variable, just a preprocessor macro used to make the code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: I'm getting at the fact that an array is just some number of consecutive objects of the element-type. But you use a pointer to that array in addition. That means your code will redirect through that extra-variable, especially as it is neither constant nor file-local. (The notation being the same does not meant that the semantics are the same.)

Comment: @Deduplicator I intended to use `L` because I knew it was adequate for this case. `LL` may have been a bit more "harmonious", but the upcast is harmless.

Comment: Is it? A `long` need not be bigger that 32  bits. And it is not on windows.

Comment: @Deduplicator Can you provide a standards document that indicates what you just noted? In both cases, they are just base addresses. AFAIK, no additional indirection takes place. Also, it's the simplest way to make the data read only and guarantee compiler warnings will occur if the developer attempts to modify it. If you intend for the data to remain the same throughout execution, lock it down.

Comment: @Deduplicator I could make 64-bit fixed-width, but I'm going to leave the rest to OP to figure out on his own. I'm going on the assumption he's using a modern OS and chip. If he's working on embedded systems, he should already know about this.

Comment: pointer and array are fundamentally different types, even though an array decays to a pointer to it first element in most contexts. That pointer is an rvalue, as there's no object backing it. (BTW: Most consider windows7 and later to be fairly modern systems, and there `long` is 32 bits.

Comment: @Deduplicator Then could you please provide an example or assembly dump analysis that clearly indicates additional CPU over due to the use I proposed? Also, do you have anything to say against making the copy of the string literal read-only? That's a pretty important justification I made.

Comment: Making everything you can `const` is certainly the way to go. Your code will have extra-instruction, because it must first load the pointer (from a known address), before indexing through it, instead of indexing from a known address. Of course, whole-program-optimization might be able to deduce the pointer is never changed, nor its address needed, and thus optimize the first case to the last case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way to deal with phone numbers is to consider them as a string. You'll need a string type for "formatting" your outputs and also to verify that a phone number follow a certain "regular expression" when considering user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In C all datatypes have a fixed size. Typically an `int` is a 32 bit value (but it doesn't have to be) so it will have a maximum value of 2,147,483,647.

Your value, 9,992,223,333 exceeds this value, which it why you are getting a warning. You need to use a bigger datatype like a 64 bit number. This will typically either be a `long long` if you're on Windows, or a `long` if you're on Linux.

Comment: or even better to use uint64_t to be platform independed. It is defined in stdint.h and compatible with C99

Answer (score 0):

To understand why this is happening, you need to understand how the numbers are represented in memory. I will try to give you a glimpse of the basic way they work and some further references in case you are interested. As the computer understands just 0 and 1, base 2 is the obvious choice. But there is a problem with representing negative numbers. There are some representations, like the sign-magnitude representation (basically, have a bit that represents the sign - if it is set, the number is negative), that are very simple. The problem is that such representations have 2 ways of representing 0: +0 and -0. So, a clever representation, called two's complement is used. For a binary number abcd (where a, b, c, d represent its bits), the base 10 value is a*2^3+b*2^2+c*2^1+d*2^0. If this number was a 2's complement 4-bit representation, its base 10 value would be -a*2^3+b*2^2+c*2^1+d*2^0. So, in two's complement, the first bit has a negative weight. In a 4-bit two's complement representation, if you have 0111 (decimal 7) and you try to add 1, you will get 1000, which is -8. This is called an overflow. Overflow arises just when adding numbers with the same sign and obtaining a result of different sign (adding 2 positive numbers results a negative number or adding 2 negative numbers results a positive number).

In your program, something similar happens. The only difference is that int has 32 bits, not 4.

Further references:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Answer (score 0):

The range of a signed 32-bit integer is [-2147483648, 2147483647].  You try to represent your phone number as a signed integer.

```
a. When phone num is 1112223333, it's less than the max 2147483647, so you get theright output.

b. 2222223333 is greater than the max 2147483647, but can still be represented as a 32-bit number, you get the 2's complement number which is -2072743963

c. 9992223333 cannot be represented by a 32-bit number, i.e. it's even bigger than (2^32 - 1), that's why you such error.
```